# Confused with generating batch data for skip gram model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp

So when I was checking the implementation of a skip gram model in tensorflow using a movie dataset. I came across this function:

```
def generate_batch_data(sentences, batch_size, window_size, method='skip_gram'):
    # Fill up data batch
    batch_data = []
    label_data = []
    while len(batch_data) < batch_size:
        # select random sentence to start
        rand_sentence = np.random.choice(sentences)
        # Generate consecutive windows to look at
        window_sequences = [rand_sentence[max((ix-window_size),0):(ix+window_size+1)] for ix, x in enumerate(rand_sentence)]
        # Denote which element of each window is the center word of interest
        label_indices = [ix if ix<window_size else window_size for ix,x in enumerate(window_sequences)]

        # Pull out center word of interest for each window and create a tuple for each window
        if method=='skip_gram':
            batch_and_labels = [(x[y], x[:y] + x[(y+1):]) for x,y in zip(window_sequences, label_indices)]
            # Make it in to a big list of tuples (target word, surrounding word)
            tuple_data = [(x, y_) for x,y in batch_and_labels for y_ in y]
        elif method=='cbow':
            batch_and_labels = [(x[:y] + x[(y+1):], x[y]) for x,y in zip(window_sequences, label_indices)]
            # Make it in to a big list of tuples (target word, surrounding word)
            tuple_data = [(x_, y) for x,y in batch_and_labels for x_ in x]
        else:
            raise ValueError('Method {} not implemented yet.'.format(method))

        # extract batch and labels
        batch, labels = [list(x) for x in zip(*tuple_data)]
        batch_data.extend(batch[:batch_size])
        label_data.extend(labels[:batch_size])
    # Trim batch and label at the end
    batch_data = batch_data[:batch_size]
    label_data = label_data[:batch_size]

    # Convert to numpy array
    batch_data = np.array(batch_data)
    label_data = np.transpose(np.array([label_data]))

    return(batch_data, label_data)
```

But I have been trying to understand the code for days but haven't figured it out. The whole code is [here](https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook/blob/master/07_Natural_Language_Processing/04_Working_With_Skip_Gram_Embeddings/04_working_with_skipgram.ipynb) if you want to have a broader perspective.

So, in the code, we have a number for the most frequent 10000 words. And we pass sentences in numeric form to the function above. Since this is a skip-gram model, we have to look at adjacent words. But how is that done in this algorithm? Wouldn't `window_sequences = [rand_sentence[max((ix-window_size),0):(ix+window_size+1)] for ix, x in enumerate(rand_sentence)]` create a window of words that are adjacent in frequency but not in sentence usage?
I would love a clarification here.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following sentence as tokens:

```
sentence = ["the","book","is","on","the","table"]
```

and consider a `window_size` of 3.
The code that builds `window_sequences` can be reformulated like this:

```
for ix in range(len(sentence)):
    x = sentence[ix] #so this is the ix-th word of the sentence
    from_index = max((ix-window_size) # this is the initial index of the window
    to_index = (ix+window_size+1) # this is the final index of the windows (excluding itself)
    window = sentence[from_index, to_index] # we pick the words of the sentence
```

Now let's run this code for some `ix`:

```
ix=0, x="the", from_index=0, to_index=4, window = ["the", "book", "is", "on"]
ix=3, x="on", from_index=0, to_index=7, window = ["the", "book", "is", "on", "the", "table"]
```

As you see it is constructing windows of words and they are exactly portions of original sentences.

A problem you could have encountered in analyzing this code is that sentence words are substituted with a numeric id in such a way as that the more frequent a word is the lower its id.

So the sentence before would appear like:

```
sentence = [2,45,7,13,2,67]
```

They are not sorted in frequency-order but they exactly keep the order in the sentence. Only their surface form is changed from `string` to `int` but you can easily understand the code on the string version.

Comment: I couldn't have asked a more intuitive answer. Thanks a lot!